# Algorithm to check intersection between two objects

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, collision-detection, intersection

I'm programming a little game and I'm having some problems with the intersections. I need an efficient algorithm to check if two objects (which have x and y coords. and also a width and an height) are intersecting.

I tried with the following, but it doesn't always work, sometimes it doesn't recnognize an intersection.

```
    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    if ((x < this.x + this.width) && (x >= this.x) && (y < this.y + this.height) && (y >= this.y))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I have an ArrayList containing the objects, and I do the following:

```
    private boolean checkIntersection(String pDirection) {

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
        if (pDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("right") && car.contains(walls.get(i).getX() - 1, walls.get(i).getY()))
            return true;
        if (pDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("left") && car.contains(walls.get(i).getX() + 30, walls.get(i).getY()))
            return true;
        if (pDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("top") && car.contains(walls.get(i).getX(), walls.get(i).getY() + 30))
            return true;
        if (pDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("down") && car.contains(walls.get(i).getX(), walls.get(i).getY() - 1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that "-1" and "+30" is to avoid the car enter the "walls", there the walls have a width of 30 and an height of 30. The car also has the same dimensions.

Also note that the x and y are the top-left cords of the rectangles. The car and the walls are rectangles.

I would be thankful for your help.

INFO: It doesn't recnognize an intersection at the beginn of a row of walls if I am above the wall and I change the direction to "down" or viceversa. 
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hp29.png)

EDIT 1 (I tried inverting the objects, but it also doesn't always work):

```
private boolean checkIntersection(String pDirection) {

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
        if (pDirection.equals("right") && walls.get(i).contains(car.getX() + 30, car.getY()))
            return false;
        if (pDirection.equals("left") && walls.get(i).contains(car.getX() - 1, car.getY()))
            return false;
        if (pDirection.equals("top") && walls.get(i).contains(car.getX(), car.getY() - 1))
            return false;
        if (pDirection.equals("down") && walls.get(i).contains(car.getX(), car.getY() + 30))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It also works without ".equals("..")", the problem is somewhere else, there as I said, it doesn't recnognize an intersection only sometimes... @Aominè

Comment: is your intention to compare the _reference_ of the `string` objects or their contents?

Comment: @Aominè this is not my priority. It works with and without equals. I need the intersection algorithm.

Comment: If you want you can use `JavaFx`  there is a class called `BoundingBox` with very useful methods... it does all you want... have a look at the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/geometry/BoundingBox.html

Comment: @Yahya thanks for the info, but to implement it I should change hundreds of lines, I would like to create the "algorithm" only for the intersection, I don't need the rest..

Comment: BTW, `pDirection == "right"` compare references, change them all to `pDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("the required direction") `.

Comment: @Yahya I know it, but it's not my priority there it works even with ==

Comment: Shouldn't you check for walls.get(i).contains(car.getX(), car.getY()); ? The other way round. Possibly adding moving direction to the car's coordinates.

Comment: @maraca check the Edit 1 please

Comment: Search for "axis aligned bounding box intersection." You'll find a gajillion references.  Here's one: http://gamemath.com/2011/09/detecting-whether-two-boxes-overlap/

Comment: It's easier to specify the conditions for a non-intersection than an intersection. Considering the x axis only, two objects A and B do not intersect if the left side of A is to the right of the right side of B, or the right side of A is to the left of the left side of B. Same goes for top/bottom in the y axis. If the two objects do not overlap on either axis (logical OR) there is no intersection. Any other possible case means they intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved modifying the contains method in the following way, and it now works perfectly:

```
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        if ((x < this.x + this.width) && (x > this.x-this.width) && (y < this.y + this.height) && (y > this.y-this.height))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I think that I did it involuntarily (checking for non-intersection instead of intersection), but I can optimize it using the answer/suggestion of @samgak and @Gene. So thanks, problem solved.

Comment: This is definitely not a solution. It will start not to work for one day :) i.e. you changed the dimensions. Consider the case, one rectangle is at point (200,200) having size (20, 20), and the other is at (100, 210) having size (100, 100). They definitely intersect, but if you call contains method of the first one with parameters (x,y)=(100,210), you will have false.

Comment: As I said, I can optimize it. And it will always work in my case, there the dimensions are fixed, I won't need to change them.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your algorithm is, you are always checking the left-top point of the wall whether it is *in* the car. However, this is not equivalent to having intersection.

Instead, you should check whether any one of the objects contains (at least) one corner (not necessarily the top left one) of the other object.

Note that you should perform this check for both sides, i.e. either the car contains any corner of the wall or the wall contains any corner of the car.